# CSRF and Multer - Invalid CSRF Token Error

Tags: node.js, express, csrf, multer

I have run into an issue with my multipart form when I added support for CSRF tokens to keep submissions secure. I have set CSRF generation globally to my `req` object in my `app.js` file and don't have problems with any other type of web form except for multipart. I have read where this is common issue with multer and related to either the placement of CSRF in conjunction with multer setup or attach it as a query on submission. I would rather not go with the approach of attaching a query because of security reasons and would prefer to see how to fix my setup to run like my other forms.

**Error message:**

```
ForbiddenError: invalid csrf token
    at csrf (/Users/user/Desktop/Projects/node/test-app/node_modules/csurf/index.js:112:19)
```

**app.js:**

```
var csrf = require('csurf');
....

//Set CSRF for Form Tokens
app.use(csrf());
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    res.locals._csrf = req.csrfToken();
    next();
});
```

**Route:**

```
var upload = multer({
    storage: multerS3({
        s3: s3,
        bucket: options.Bucket,
        contentType: multerS3.AUTO_CONTENT_TYPE,
        acl: options.ACL,
        key: function(req, file, cb){
            var fileNameFormatted = file.originalname.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase();
            cb(null, req.user.organizationId + '/' + uploadDate + '/' + fileNameFormatted);
        }
    }),
    fileFilter: function(req, file, cb){
        if(!file.originalname.match(/\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|csv|xls|xlsb|xlsm|xlsx)$/)){
            return cb('One of your selected files is not supported', false);
        }
        cb(null, true);
    }
}).array('fileUpload', 5);


appRoutes.route('/blog/create')

.get(function(req, res){
    res.render('pages/app/blog-create.hbs',{
        errorMessage: req.flash('error'),
        csrfToken: req.csrfToken()
    });
})

.post(function(req, res){

upload(req, res, function(err){
            if(err){
                req.flash('error', err);
                res.redirect(req.get('referer'));
                return;
            }

 models.Blog.create({
                date: req.body.date,
                title: req.body.title,
                content: req.body.content,
                userId: req.user.userId     
            }).then(function(){
                req.flash('info', 'Blog was successfully created.');
                res.redirect('/app');
            });
})
});
```

**view:**

```
<form action="/app/blog/create" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="blogSubmission">
                <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="{{csrfToken}}">

....
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just need to add Multer before csurf -

```
app.use(multer().single('image-field-name'));
app.use(csurf());
```

And make sure to pass the `_csrf` value during POST -

```
<input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="<%= csrfToken %>">
```

**If above solution doesn't works, then just add "_csrf" value on the POST action -**

```
<form action="/admin/?_csrf=<%=csrfToken%>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

hi :) this is a little bit late but (first of all i'm may not be a good English speaker so if you see any grammar or speling error use

```
{try(){understand()}catch(e){/*do nothing :)*/}}
```

method :) )

i had your problem last month and it was so bad that i couldn't find a good answer

but here you are :)))   (honestly i'm not very good at reading others code so read my answer and figure it out how to edit your code)

honestly there is no good answer if you want to use the usual posting forms methods (there is a way which suggest you to first get and save the file then check it's csrf which i really didn't like too much)but if you are willing to do a little hard front end javascript then you are on your good day:

the whole idea is to set a header for your form and then send it(all using **AJAX** and **JQuery**):

here is a small example of how you should do it:

```
$.ajax({
    cache: false,
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'the URL you want to post to',
    contentType: "what ever you want",
    headers: {"X-CSRF-TOKEN": csrfToken},
    data: your data,
    success: function (res) {
        some code after you get a response from server
        console.log(res)
    }
})
```